# Is there an adjective for "closing in"?

Tags: word-request

> The closing-in walls are about to crush us!

> The ____ walls are about to crush us!

I was thinking about encroaching, but it implies more than just "closing in", is there a good adjective for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **claustrophobic**

The *American Heritage Dictionary* defines it as

> Uncomfortably closed or hemmed in.

Comment: It doesn't imply an ever closing-in movement.